# iOS, 2 UIContainerViews in 1 UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

Simple enough, I wish to hold two `UIContainerViews` in a single `UIViewController`.

Using storyboard, I can add them both in, but then any adjustment made to each container size, results in the containers disappearing with only the segue left visible.

Is this a storyboard bug, or does it represent a restriction on holding two containers in the same view?

Comment: How are you adjusting the size?  In storyboard? In the view controller? In the contained view controller?  I built a quick project with a view containing two view controllers (using auto layout)and was able to resize the views just fine.

Comment: hmmm, i was adjusting the size of the container's within the view controller of which they are both contained. i'm guessing from the lack of response to this question that one is able to add 2 containers to a view, and that my issue is something else i'm missing

Comment: Perhaps. Make sure you are using auto layout.  Also, try coloring the contained views different colors to track their location.  If you are adjusting the views in storyboard, their should be no problem, unless they are falling behind other views.

Answer (score 0):

If the embed segues are still there, the containers are still there. My guess is the frames got updated and didn't have enough constraints to determine their size, so they went to zero. This happens to me frequently when I am in the process of creating their constraints. I would adjust their size through their constraints and I'll bet that fixes your issue.